# Method 'range' of Object '_global' failed error when I am trying to paste

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy 12 cells (1 row, 12 columns) and paste it to a different location in the same sheet.

```
 For j = 1 To 519
For k = 2 To 519
    b = "K" & CStr(k)
    c = "AA" & CStr(k)
    Set x = Range(b)
    Set y = Range(c)
    If x = y Then
        For a = 2 To 519
            d = "M" & CStr(a)
            e = "x" & CStr(a)
            s = "AC" & CStr(a)
            Set dd = Range(d)
            Set ee = Range(e)
            Set ss = Range(s)
            Range("dd:ee").Select
            Selection.copy
            Range("ss").PasteSpecial = xlPasteAll
```

I'm getting an error at the paste section of the code, saying "Method 'range' of Object '_global' failed error."

Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: If x = y Then   'this will never be true.  Do you mean the values of these cells?   Range"dd:ee") is the range including column DD and EE, not the values you have given the variables EE and DD.   Also, why are you making all these variable as ranges?  Lose the "= xlPasteAll"

Comment: Yes, by x=y I mean the values of these cells. What should I write so that the values given to variables EE and DD is considered and not the columns ?
And I got rid of "=xlPasteAll", still the error comes up.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the end if and nexts 
J,k, a, b, d, e, and s are all just variables (should be string)

```
      For j = 1 To 519    
        For k = 2 To 519
         b = "K" & k
         c = "AA" & k
         Set x = Range(b)
         Set y = Range(c)
         If x.value = y.value Then
             For a = 2 To 519
                 d = "M" & a)
                 e = "X" & a
                 s = "AC" & a
                 Range(d & ":" & e).copy Range(s).PasteSpecial 
             End If
         Next K  
     Next J
```